# Change row color jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently loading an asp.net datagrid view. In the view, I am returning results for a query, amongst there's a column named "last_payment". I want to change the color for all rows where last_payment is less than 5 days. How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you make [fiddle](http://jsffidle.net) with your code?

Comment: Give your condition in RowDataBound event

Answer (score 0):

You can change row-background color using `RowDataBound` event ..

In ur aspx file

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">

</asp:GridView>
```

and In ur code file

```
        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
         {
             if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
             {
             //here you can compate date this is just for example..
                 if(last_payment>DateTime.Now().AddDays(-5))
                       {
                        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F3F7AC");
                        }
              } 
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    if ((Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[0]) > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5)))
    { 
        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#cccccc"); 
    } 
}
```

Give the above code in `RowDataBound` Event.

Note: Change `Cells[0]` according to your `gridview`.